# nss 3.35 issue with nspr 4.19 PR_GetEnvSecure function

Tags: nss

I am getting the following error while building nss 3.35 version

secoid.c:(.text.SECOID_Init+0x36): undefined reference to `PR_GetEnvSecure'
secoid.c:(.text.SECOID_Init+0x55): undefined reference to`PR_GetEnvSecure'

I am using nspr version 4.19 to build this.
Here is my command to build nss

make -j1 BUILD_OPT=1 NSPR_INCLUDE_DIR=nss-3.36.1/nspr/include/nspr USE_SYSTEM_ZLIB=1 ZLIB_LIBS=-lz NSS_ENABLE_WERROR=0 $([ $(uname -m ) = x86_64 ] && echo USE_64=1 ) $([ -f /usr/include/sqlite3.h ] && echo NSS_USE_SYSTEM_SQLITE=1 )

Comment: Here are last few lines from compilation log

/dist/Linux3.10_x86_64_cc_glibc_PTH_64_OPT.OBJ/lib -lplc4 -lplds4 -lnspr4  -lpthread  -ldl -lc
Linux3.10_x86_64_cc_glibc_PTH_64_OPT.OBJ/secoid.o: In function `SECOID_Init':
secoid.c:(.text.SECOID_Init+0x36): undefined reference to `PR_GetEnvSecure'
secoid.c:(.text.SECOID_Init+0x55): undefined reference to `PR_GetEnvSecure'
Linux3.10_x86_64_cc_glibc_PTH_64_OPT.OBJ/secport.o: In function `SetupUseFreeList':
secport.c:(.text.SetupUseFreeList+0xc): undefined reference to

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar issue reported in [Red Hat Bugzilla 1458841](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1458841).

In that case they removed the dependency on this object.

In Red Hat 7.6 this object is defined in library "/lib64/libnspr4.so" as you can see below.

## objdump -TC /lib64/libnspr4.so | grep PR_GetEnvSecure

0000000000019b60 g    DF .text  0000000000000067  Base        PR_GetEnvSecure

You need to build NPSR library version that defines this object, for example version 4.19